# Razor generates different HTML after published to a shared host

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-validation

Model class:

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    ......
    [MaxLength(9), Required, DisplayName("Social security number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid social security number")]
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SocialSecurityNumber, new { id = "ssn" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SocialSecurityNumber)
```

Generated code when running in Visual studio 2012/Chrome.

```
<input data-val="true" 
  data-val-regex="Invalid social security number" 
  data-val-regex-pattern="\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}" 
  data-val-required="The Social security number field is required." 
  id="ssn" 
  name="SocialSecurityNumber" 
  type="text" 
  value="" 
  class="input-validation-error">
<span 
  class="field-validation-error" 
  data-valmsg-for="SocialSecurityNumber" 
  data-valmsg-replace="true">
  <span for="ssn" class="" style="">Invalid social security number</span>
</span>
```

Generated code after publishing to shared host

```
<input 
  data-val="true" 
  data-val-regex="Invalid social security number" 
  data-val-regex-pattern="\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}" 
  data-val-required="The Social security number field is required." 
  id="ssn" 
  name="SocialSecurityNumber" 
  type="text" 
  value="">
<span 
   class="field-validation-valid" 
   data-valmsg-for="SocialSecurityNumber" 
   data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Why the site running via VS has more generated html codes? (      `class="input-validation-error">`, etc.
)

Comment: Are you getting the validation error on the hosted site?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two situations -

The first example shows a textbox with *invalid* input, hence the css class `input-validation-error` and the message within the `SPAN`.

The second example shows *valid* (or no) input, hence the lack of a CSS class on the textbox and no message in the `SPAN`.

Put an invalid SSN in the form on each site and submit it and see if you don't get the same results.

Comment: The client side validation doesn't work on the shared host. It works on local VS host.